# How do I get the voltage to stay at 5V when using air pumps?

Tags: arduino, motor

[image: I added the power supply and the ground to the arduino, I replace the solenoid valves by inductors][image: Air Pump specification][image: Solenoid valve specification]

I have a design where I am using 2 mini air motors pumps of (3 V each, rated current< 150mA each,) 2 release valves (5V each and 263mA each.)

The Arduino microcontroller sends 5V to the motors and the release valves.

As of right now, the voltage drops when the motor kicks and when the LCD kicks in.

We want to resolve that issue to have a steady 5V baseline.

I tried to remove the transistors and replace them with flyback diodes but it didn't work. I also tried keeping the transistors and adding flyback diodes to the pumps and the release valves, no result.

I tried designing a flyback converter but I have a tons of questions regarding the choice of the values.

Would that help?
How do I get the voltage to stay at 5V?

Comment: From the schematic it appears that you are sourcing the motors 5V and GND from the arudino. What does the PCB layout look like?

Comment: Your circuit has no power supply, so that diagram can't be right.  What is providing the 5v?  Can is supply enough current?

Comment: OP appears to be using the Arduino's onboard power supply. It is obviously not enough and sagging under load. A flyback converter will not help because it cannot create more power from the Arduino's limited power supply. OP It can only shuffle redistribute the existing power between voltage and current. OP needs to power the motors off a second power supply independent of the Arduino. Get a AC-DC wall wart and use that.

Comment: Arduino Mega2560 R3 seems to use NCP1117ST50T3G (1A). I think a datasheet to the motors and valves could be useful. And maybe a picture of the setup, the pinheader to motor/valve arrangement especially.

Comment: _"I also tried ... adding flyback diodes to the pumps and the release valves"_ - you need those anyway. Keep them in!

Comment: You seem to be giving 5 V to motors rated at 3 V. This is not a recipe for happy motors.

Comment: Arduino releases a maximum current of 40mA. Use a external source on the transistors collector.

Answer (score 2):

You have motors for 3V at 350 mA. At 5V they will draw more current. You have 2 other solenoids at 263 mA.

The arduini mega 2650 has a usb in thats hard limited to 500 mA by a poly fuse. And the barrel input at 1A rated diode and a linear regulator thats only really good to 800 mA output. We don't know what your supply is at as that can cause other issues. With your motors and solenoids alone thats already over 1 Amp.

Plus your 2n2222 are being driven at 5V - 0.7V / 120 ohm = 35 mA each. That introduces more current draw through the arduino regulator. It also causes issues as each pin is rated at 40mA max with significant voltage droop, plus i think your running these all of the same port on the microcontroller and that has a total port maximum too.

And I see no power capacitors so large quick changes in the power lines will cause drops.

Suggestions: power the motors and solenoids off their own supply/regulator. Add a 1000 uF capacitor near the arduino, and near the power supply for the motors. Reduce your arduino outputs to 20mA per pin. A 240 ohm resistor would do that instead of 120 ohm. 20 mA at the 2n2222 transistor base will still put it in full saturation for a 350 mA collector current.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one right answer, but when motors or solenoids are involved, you want to power them separately from the computer.

Motors and solenoids are very "dirty" loads -- they present a highly varying load, which act like they're injecting all sorts of high-frequency current (hash) into your power supply.  This makes the supply they draw from vary a lot in voltage -- they are dirty and noisy.  Microprocessors want *clean*, *quiet* supplies.

The best thing to do would be to power your board from some raw supply, off of which you take both your motor supply and your processor supply.  Because of the way you're driving the motors and solenoids, you can just replace your computer's +5V supply line with your "dirty" +5V line.

Comment: What do you mean by a dirty +5V line. Can you explain more?

Comment: Edited to define "dirty" in the context of a voltage supply.